# Element changes class selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I try to access two dropdowns using selenium and python. The first problem is that, the class for second button is not too stable meaning, after selecting an option, the class name is changing.
__________ SECOND BUTTON _____________

```
awsui-select-trigger-placeholder
```

Before:
[image]
After selecting first option:

[image]

____________ FIRST BUTTON _____________

Second issue is that the first button has same class

```
awsui-select-trigger-label
```

Before:
[image]

After selecting the option:

[image]
Is there a way I could access the class more dynamically?

I'm using this code for the second button:

```
att3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                ec.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (By.CLASS_NAME,
                     'awsui-select-trigger-placeholder')))
```

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Can you share bit more HTML ? with tag name and it's attribute

Comment: @cruisepandey I have edited the question, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of locating by entire class name

```py
att3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,                     'awsui-select-trigger-placeholder')))
```

You can use this XPath locator

```py
att3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,                     '//*[contains(@class,"awsui-select-trigger-")]')))
```

Or css selector like this:

```py
att3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,                     '[class*="awsui-select-trigger-"]')))
```

I can't validate uniqueness of the locators above since you didn't share a link to the page you are working on.
Also I would advice you to use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `element_to_be_clickable` if it can be applicable on that element.
**UPD**
Since class name attribute is changing for both elements you can construct the locators based on their parent elements.
So the first element can be clicked as following:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,                     '//span[@id="awsui-select-0-textbox"]//span[contains(@class,"awsui-select-trigger-")]'))).click()
```

Or even

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,                     '//span[@id="awsui-select-0-textbox"]/span'))).click()
```

While the second element can be clicked by:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,                     '//span[@id="awsui-select-21-textbox"]//span[contains(@class,"awsui-select-trigger-")]'))).click()
```

Or respectively

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,                     '//span[@id="awsui-select-21-textbox"]/span'))).click()
```

Comment: thank you but once I click on element and select an option, from 'awsui-select-trigger-placeholder' it changes to 'awsui-select-trigger-label'. Unfortunately, even if I provide the link, you will not be able to access it.

Comment: The locators above matching both `awsui-select-trigger-placeholder` and `awsui-select-trigger-label`.

Comment: Understood, the previous button I click, also have this class 'awsui-select-trigger-label', is there any exception I can add here?Thank you so much again

Comment: But I still don't understand the scenario. Is there 2 different buttons? You wrote the class attribute is changing so I thought it is the same element...

Comment: yes yes the same button and class changes when I select an option. But before I access that button, I click on another button and the class for that is 'awsui-select-trigger-label' so while using the method you've shared, it clicks on the first button

Comment: Can you describe the scenario so I (and others) will be able to understand? How / what are you clicking / selecting? What element is changing by selecting the option? Please give a whole, entire information 1 time so it will be clear.

Comment: updated the question, hope is much clearer now, thank you

Comment: Can you share HTML of both element before and after selecting the first option? Currently you shared only the first element HTML before selecting

Comment: done, I have updated

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this once:

Collect both the dropdowns and use indexing to click on them.

```
The xpaths should highlight only those two dropdowns. As per the information you have shared, xpath might be like this.
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='awsui-select-trigger-wrapper']/span/span")
Or
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'awsui-select-trigger')]")
Or
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,'awsui-select-trigger')]")

Once you get those options
options[0].click() would click on the 1st dropdown
options[1].click() would click on the 2nd one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly going to the `span` element, there is a very useful `id` attribute that you can use to have the `CSS_SELECTOR` created using the `parent-child` relationship. Since I expect the `id` attribute to be unique, this can be used in this way-

So, the css selector would be

```
att3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#awsui-select-0-textbox > span")))
```

And similarly, the css selector using the parent child relationship for the second drop down would be

```
att4 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#awsui-select-21-textbox > span:nth-child(1)")))
```

If there are more than 1 span items inside the `#awsui-select-21-textbox` `div` element, then you can use the corresponding `nth-child` in the selector (starting from 1 as css index starts from 1).